# Navigation Stack without Gyro sensor

Tags: ros, navigation, gyro, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Is a gyro sensor so important when using nav stack?**

I applied nav stack to my robot, which does NOT have a gyro sensor.
I also have a turtlebot and setup it.

Apparently, turtlebot moves better than my robot.
My robot more often stop and rotate in that place.
I think it's because parameter tuning is not the best.
However, partly, I think it's due to no gyro sensor on my robot.

If you use nav stack without a gyro sensor,
do you feel it works well?
Without a gyro sensor,
does the capability of nav stack(Especially amcl) decay remarkably?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49820/navigation-stack-without-gyro-sensor/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-12-06**:
IMUs and Gyros are making your odometry data better. It is not necessary but consider that your odometry error because of only wheel encoders are incremental. If you want to have a better odometry without using gyros or imus, you can filter your odometry data by using robot_pose_ekf package

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-01-29**:
Thank you, I consider whether to use the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

In our lab we use Turtlebots with IRobot Roomba which does not have Gyro. I can confirm that navigation stack works great on them. Probably you just have to tune some parameters for your robot. Maybe this can help you: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

Best regards

---

Originally posted by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) with karma: 460 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-06**:
I also can confirm that move_base works fine without a gyro. It's just important that the odometry is accurate and provides accurate velocity measurements. Also, don't use map but odom as reference frame for your local costmap. The global costmap should use map though.

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-01-29**:
Thank you for your comments. I had a problem about transformation of odometry. After I solved it, my robot worked correctry.